# Write a function to generate a random number every N seconds PHP

Tags: laravel

I know this question has answers to it . My case is a little different .I am building an API using laravel, first time using it. I have a store endpoint. My UI has a button to 'Run Program'. When a user clicks Run, the program starts at 12:00:00, and keeps generating a random number every n secs, until a user clicks stop. I need help writing a function to generate random number every N seconds(30), and keep doing so infinitely .This is what I have tried, and I cannot get it work.

```
public function store(Request $request)
        { 
            date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');
            $generator = rand(10,20);
            $date = new DateTime();
            $startIncrement = new DateTime(); //start interval
            $stopIncrement = new DateTime();  //stop @ interval 
            $reportIncrement = new DateTime(); //report @ intervl
    
            $startIncrement->add(new DateInterval("PT30S"));
            $stopIncrement->modify('+40 seconds');
            $reportIncrement->modify('+50 seconds');
    
           
            $date = $date->format('h:i:s');
            $date = strtotime($date );
            $date = date('h:i:s', $date);
            
            do {
                    try {
                        $startIncrement = $startIncrement->format('h:i:s');
                        $startIncrement = strtotime($startIncrement) ;
                        $startIncrement = date('h:i:s', $startIncrement);
                       
                        $runningNServers = "Reporting" ." ". $generator ." servers" ." " ."running at" ." "  .$startIncrement;
                        
                        $Tasks = TaskType::create([                                  '                              'event'=>'START',
                           'message'=>$runningNServers,
                           'program_time'=>$startIncrement,
                           'actual_time'=>$date,
                            'display_message'=>$runningNServers,
                            'colors'=>"fff"
                           ]);
                            return $Tasks;
                            continue;
                         
                  
                    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                        throw $th;
                    }
                    
            }
            while

 ( $startIncrement === $date);
    }
```

this is a sample response  I get when I make a post request:

```
{
    "event": "START",
    "message": "Reporting 10 servers running at 11:04:42",
    "program_time": "11:04:42",
    "actual_time": "11:04:12",
    "display_message": "Reporting 10 servers running at 11:04:42",
    "colors": "fff",
    "updated_at": "2021-08-28T08:04:12.000000Z",
    "created_at": "2021-08-28T08:04:12.000000Z",
    "id": 660
}
```

if you look at the program_time and actual_time, you can tell there is a 30 sec difference.

Comment: Doing this server side might not be a good solution (Javascript might be a better solution if these are supposed to be presented back to the user at once), but it all depends on what you're actually trying to do. You'll have to move your call to `rand` inside your loop, and since you have a `return` before your `continue`, the loop will terminate the first time it runs. You also doesn't actually create a task or do anything with `$runningNServer` - what is the meaning of this variable/string?

Comment: "I cannot get it work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: @MatsLindh, I have edited the question with more info. $runningNServer just stores the time and the rand num and sends it to a db field as message.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, actually it works.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I agree, its not enough to say its not working . Its not working in the sense that, if i send a post request, which will  be an equivalent of a Button 'RUN' in my UI, my code should run infinitely. That is, every 30 secs, trigger a hardcoded event, infinitely. Or atleast when a user click stops.

Comment: @MatsLindh. Your insight was so HELPFUL. Finally ,got it to work . Thank YOU!

Answer (score 0):

For those that may ever come across this: I modified my code to the following and it works as expected. However, be aware of the Maximum execution time error: Its easily solvable though.

```
 while(true) {
            $servers = '';
            $date = new DateTime();
            $date = $date->format('h:i:s');
            $date = strtotime($date);

            if( $date % 30 == 0) { // get time in seconds and check if it is multiple of 5
                $servers = rand(10,20);
                $date = date('h:i:s', $date);
                $response = "Reported". " " .$servers ." " ." running at" ." " .$date;

                $Tasks = TaskType::create([
                            "program_time" => $date,
                            'event' => 'START',
                            "message" => $response,
                            "actual_time" => $date,
                            "display_message" => $date,
                            'colors' => '#fff'
                        ]);
                        sleep(1);
                        continue;
                        return $Tasks ;
                } 


            if( $date % 40 == 0) { // get time in seconds and check if it is multiple of 5
                $randomServerStop = rand(5, 3);
                $date = date('h:i:s', $date);
                $response = "Reported". " " .$randomServerStop ." " ." running at" ." " .$date;
    
                $Tasks = TaskType::create([
                            "program_time" => $date,
                            'event' => 'REPORT',
                            "message" => $response,
                            "actual_time" => $date,
                            "display_message" => $date,
                            'colors' => '#fff'
                        ]);
                        sleep(1);
                        continue;
                        return $Tasks;
                    } 

            if( $date % 50 == 0) { // get time in seconds and check if it is multiple of 5
                $servers = rand(10,20);
                $date = date('h:i:s', $date);
                $response = "Reported". " " .$servers ." " ." running at" ." " .$date;
        
                $Tasks = TaskType::create([
                    "program_time" => $date,
                    'event' => 'STOP',
                    "message" => $response,
                    "actual_time" => $date,
                    "display_message" => $date,
                    'colors' => '#fff'
                    ]);
                    sleep(1);
                    continue;
                    return $Tasks;
     
                        } 
                        
            else{
                        
                }
             }
        header("Refresh:5"); // refresh after 5 seconds
```